# Spring Cloud Config Server - AWS Secret Manager

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, aws-secrets-manager

I have an application used with spring cloud config server.
SpringBoot 3.0.12 - Spring Cloud 2022.0.4

This application is used from other services at startup to read configuration properties. In these properties there are Databases url, username/password etc. on a Git Repo.

I want to migrate those variables in AWS Secrets Manager, how can I do that?

pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=8888

#Properties git repo where are stored all configurations
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${config-server-git-uri}
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths={application}
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=${config-server-git-username}
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=${config-server-git-password}
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=/opt/config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=develop
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.force-pull=true

#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=aws-import-config
spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:${config-server-secret-name}
aws.secretsmanager.region=${config-server-aws-region}
```

I use already secrets for retrieve Git information to communicate with Git repository. I want to add "placeholder" on properties files placed into my repo git and replace them with values read from secrets.

Now I have this file into my repo git:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://my-funny-user:my-funny-pass@xxxxxx.net
```

I want to replace with this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://${user.mongo}:${password.mongo}@xxxxxx.net
```

and place variables `${user.mongo}` and `${password.mongo}` into secrets.

I tried to follow [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_aws_secrets_manager)